# How do I solve this :TypeError: StandardScaler.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have taken some code from GitHub that is supposed to allow me to input code that will later be analyzed and then give a 0 or 1 output that will say whether you have diabetes or not. The GitHub:https:[//github.com/MuhammadTalha-crypto/Diabetic_Prediction_Using_SVM/blob/main/Project_Diabetic_Prediction_using_SVM.ipynb]. In order to solve this issue the person who created the GitHub wrote the following "X does not have valid feature names, but StandardScaler was fitted with feature names" I interpreted this as adding x_value to the StandardScaler() function. However now it shows me the error above. So I was wondering if I interpreted the suggestion wrong or if there is a way to solve this error so my code will work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.base import ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import auc, classification_report, roc_curve
from sklearn.multioutput import ClassifierChain
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score , f1_score,confusion_matrix,classification_report, recall_score
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets


df= pd.read_csv('/Users/______/Desktop/Daiabities_1.csv', delimiter=";", decimal=",")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

df.info()
print(df.head(4))
print(df.shape)
print(df.describe())
print(df.corr())

x= df.iloc[:,0:8]
y= df.iloc[:,-1]
best_features= SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=3)
fit= best_features.fit(x,y)
df_scores= pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
df_columns= pd.DataFrame(x.columns)
features_scores= pd.concat([df_columns, df_scores], axis=1)
features_scores.columns= ['Features', 'Score']
features_scores.sort_values(by = 'Score')
print(features_scores)

x= df[['Glucose', 'Insulin', 'Age']]  
y= df[['Outcome']] 
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=100)
logreg= LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred=logreg.predict(x_test)
print (x_test) 
print (y_pred)


num_columns = len(df.columns.drop('Outcome'))
num_rows = (num_columns + 1) // 2

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5*num_rows))
for i, column in enumerate(df.columns.drop('Outcome')):
    plt.subplot(num_rows, 2, i+1)
    sns.violinplot(x=df[column], color='#2E63E6')
    plt.title(f'Violin plot of {column}')
   
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

num_columns = len(df.columns.drop('Outcome'))
num_rows = (num_columns + 1) // 2

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5*num_rows))
for i, column in enumerate(df.columns.drop('Outcome')):
    plt.subplot(num_rows, 2, i+1)
    sns.kdeplot(data=df[column], fill=True, color='#36CD40')
    plt.title(f'KDE plot of {column}')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


sns.pairplot(df, hue='Outcome', markers=["o", "s"], palette=['blue','lightgreen'])
plt.show()

models = [LogisticRegression(), DecisionTreeClassifier(),RandomForestClassifier(),SVC(kernel='poly'),MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(128),max_iter=100)]

for model in models:
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
    print(f"Model {model}")
    print(f"Accuracy score is {accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print(f"F1 score is {f1_score(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print(f"Recall is {recall_score(y_test, y_pred)}")
    print(f"Confusin Matrix\n{confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print(f"Classification report\n{classification_report(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------")


y_score = model.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1]
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

plt.plot(fpr, tpr ,label="AUC="+str(auc))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='green', lw=2, linestyle='--')
plt.title('ROC Curve')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('false Positive Rate')
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.show()



input_data=[ ]

preg= input()
gluc= input()
bloodpr= input()
skinth= input()
insu = input()
bmi= input()
dpf= input()
age= input()

input_data.extend([preg, gluc, bloodpr, skinth, insu, bmi, dpf, age])
x = df.drop(columns ='Outcome', axis = 1)
scaler = StandardScaler(x_test)
scaler.fit(x)
stand_data = scaler.transform(x)
print(scaler.n_features_in_)


classifier = svm.SVC(kernel = "linear")
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)

input_data_numpy = np.asarray(input_data)
input_data_reshaped = input_data_numpy.reshape(1,-1)
std_data = scaler.transform(input_data_reshaped)
print(std_data)

prediction = classifier.predict(std_data)
print(prediction)

if (prediction[0] == 0):
    print("The person is non-diabetic")
else:
    print("The person is diabetic")`
```

I have tried to fix the error by adding the following arguments to x_train, y_train, train and y_train, x_test, y_test, x_test and y_test to the StandardScaler() function. In all of these cases a variation of this error was given:

```
TypeError: StandardScaler.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of StandardScaler, you are obviously not using it right.

Comment: `StandardScaler` is a class, not a function: see [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html). The class constructor does not take any positional arguments.

Comment: Thank you I have taken your suggestion although I am still slightly confused. I was wondering if you would be able to answer some questions: Fit predicts y_predict values using x_train, if this is what happens why is their x_predict? Is transfer only used to store the standardized code, docent this automatically happens when something is assigned to a value like stand_data? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
scaler = StandardScaler(x_test)
```

with the following:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
```

The above line would initiate the `StandardScaler` class. Then you can fit and transform your data with the scaler:

```
scaler.fit(your_data)
scaler.transform(your_data)
```